# Pls tell me how to undo both sides delete like in my video. (VS-code)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

[Short video about my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4noNk.gif)

I tried to uninstall all extensions and reset setting to default, but it does not work. Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Provide debugging details and a clear description of the problem. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Images (and videos) are discouraged and often downvoted: [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) As it stands, we have no idea what this is about (unless we watch your video, which many people will not do).

Comment: You need to elaborate. What's the problem? What isn't working how you want it to? What exactly is the behaviour that you want? How can the issue be procedurally reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple go to VS-code and go to Extensions and uninstall this extensions `Auto Rename Tag`

[image]

[Docs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag)

Comment: VS Code already supports linked editing out of the box...

Comment: I already done it before I post this, but It still not working .